# Where can I translate and validate as true a Spanish Sephardic Ketubah?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, translation, ketubah

I have a Ketubah from my grandparent's wedding in Aleppo that needs to be translated and validated as a true Sephardic/Spanish Ketubah.  Where can I have this done?

Comment: Hi elias. If you are trying to translate this to use as proof in a court case, such as in a Jewish court ("Beit Din") to prove Jewish lineage, I highly recommend you consult with the court to determine what sorts of regulations it has about acceptable translators and what identifiers can be used to determine authenticity.